# Refactoring: Removing renamed packages (automatically)

Tags: ada, gnat

Ada supports the renaming of packages ([see here)](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-8-5-3.html).

Unfortunately I have to work on some legacy Ada code and the previous developer renamed packages excessively: more than 100 renames in a single package specification/body are not unusual. In my opinion it is hard to read the Ada code, especially because the renames are not consistent.

So I thought about removing such renames and replace all usages of the renamed package identifier with the original package identifier. I could do it by hand but before starting I would like to know if this task could be automated?

After the removal of all renamed packages I would like to check for each compilation unit if the original code and the refactored code have the same semantic. Could this be done by the compiler output?

Comment: This sounds like an editor find/replace activity. First search for all the renames clauses then substitute all instances of a renamed package with its original package identifier. When that is complete delete all lines containing the renames clause. Of course, you could write your own utility to do this using the language of your choice.

Comment: If you have >100 package renames, you must have >100 `with`’s! Truly excessive.

Comment: If you’re prepared to build a tool, you _might_ find [libadalang](https://github.com/AdaCore/libadalang) useful.

Comment: Sounds like something [AdaControl](http://www.adalog.fr/compo/adacontrol_ug.html) might be up to. It's a semantic parser using ASIS (not unlike libadalang), for checking rules (a coding standard, for example). As output you can get suggested fixes, which is recognized interactively if using Gnat Programming Studio, giving a wrench symbol to click on in the Locations window. There's also a tool to apply the fixes automatically. (I haven't used AdaControl to any extent myself, so can't provide more help than the link to the user's guide...)

Comment: GPS has a "Refactor" choice in its context menu. Right click on an identifier and it comes up. I don't know if it can do what you want. Also, Adalog has Adasubst which might do what you want.